# mongoose - request body using string for array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create request body (form-data) for an array using name (String). But it only let me using the ObjectId.

Some code for storing the data

```js
const Product = require('./model');
const Category = require('../category/model');
const Tag = require('../tag/model');

...

async function store(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let payload = req.body;
        ...
        if (payload.tags && payload.tags.length) {

            let tags = await Tag.find({ name: { $in: payload.tags } });

            if (tags.length) {
                payload = { ...payload, tags: tags.map(tag => tag._id) }
            }
        }
        ...
    } catch (err) {
        if (err && err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            return res.json({
                error: 1,
                message: err.message,
                fields: err.errors
            });
        }

        next(err);
    }
}
```

Returned success when using ObjectId for the tags. But error when using the name (String)

Error message : **"Product validation failed: tags.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["value"]" (type string) at path "tags.0""**

[Success example](https://i.ibb.co/dpkXs6d/success-return.jpg)

[Failed example](https://i.ibb.co/N1Cqc0S/failed-return.jpg)

Product model schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { model, Schema } = mongoose;

const productSchema = Schema({

    ...

    // One-To-One
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },

    // One-To-Many
    tags: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }]

}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = model('Product', productSchema);
```

Tags model schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { model, Schema } = mongoose;

const tagSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        minlength: [3, 'Min length is 3 character!'],
        maxlength: [20, 'Max length is 20 character!'],
        required: [true, 'Tag name must be filled!']
    }
});

module.exports = model('Tag', tagSchema)
```

Any idea? I spend days to solve it but still no result

Comment: In your schema, the tags must explicitely be `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId`. It makes sense that the validation fails if you are trying to set them as "es" or "kopi". They must be Mongo IDs.

Comment: @JeremyThille did change the `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId` into `type: Array` can solve the problem? or there are any other solution to make "es", "kopi" into req.body?

Comment: The problem is, `tags` is a reference to the "Tags" collection. So it must be an array of ObjectId (because then you populate the documents). It can't be a string, it has to be an ObjectId. If you want it to be "kopi", it means one of the documents in the collection has an ObjectId==="kopi", which is not a valid ObjectId.

Comment: @JeremyThille alright thanks for the info. I found alternative solution for the front-end. I'll not mark it as done if someone had another way to solve it.